# Parsing FNC1 character with bwip-js gs1datamatrix

Tags: barcode, gs1-datamatrix, gs1-ai-syntax, bwip-js

What I want is to generate a GS1 datamatrix using the bwip-js API with a FNC1 passed in.

I have tried the example provided in their website ([Online Barcode API documentation](https://github.com/metafloor/bwip-js/wiki/Online-Barcode-API)) throught Postman and it returns the correct value back (ie. without the FNC1 character in the scanned result).

Their example request (parses FNC1 correctly)

```
http://bwipjs-api.metafloor.com/?bcid=code128&text=%5EFNC1011234567890&parsefnc&alttext=%2801%291234567890
```

However when I use my example for the GS1 data matrix, with the FNC1 value, I get the FNC1 in the scanned result. So it is not parsing the FNC1 value correctly.

My request (does not parse FNC1 correctly):

```
http://bwipjs-api.metafloor.com/?bcid=gs1datamatrix&text=%5EFNC1(01)03453120000011(17)120508(10)ABCD1234(410)9501101020917&parsefnc&alttext=%2801%291234567890
```

I have read all the documentation and articles I can find about their generator and the FNC1 character, but didn't give me any clues.

Am I doing anything wrong here?

**UPDATE:**

The input to BWIP-JS:

```
(01)99312650999998(91)111JD507496002000960300(420)2164(8008)181102113732
```

Image generated:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in [bwip-js](https://github.com/metafloor/bwip-js/blob/eda7c22e969791dce5ffb6b3bdda2c553b9d9248/barcode.ps#L23903) is PostScript and I'm no expert in that language.  But try taking the 'FNC1' out of your request and see if that works.

I think it's trying to automatically add FNC1 to any GS1 Datamatrix (see section starting a line 23903) when it sees an AI, whereas for Data Matrix it has to be explicitly requested.

Comment: Looks like it. I have done this change and awaiting approval from the client. Will update as soon as I get a response.

Comment: @charlesbridge @Terry Burton The client barcode reader didn't pick up any FNC1 characters unfortunately. I left out FNC1 from the request and removed the 'parsefnc' before sending it. I tried sending the request with and without the brackets in the application identifier as well. But to no avail. Any idea why? They use `Webscan Trucheck` as the barcode verifier. If that makes any difference I don't know.

Comment: If you could please update the original question with the input to BWIP-JS that you are now trying and the image that it is generating then I'll investigate on the basis of what is provided.

Comment: (Preserving the original question when updating, of course!)

Comment: @Kavo You are generating an image using the datamatrix encoder, not gs1datamatrix as you provided in your initial description.

Comment: This is indeed the case @TerryBurton! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The FNC1 character is invisible to the console, so it can be tricky to see, but I've managed to parse it out of raw strings using the following:

```
var decoded = decodedString.split(decodeURI("%1D"));
```

If you're getting the FNC codes in parentheses, you could probably use a REGEX to remove them.